# Is it worth using the Hibernate Bytecode Enhancement mechanism?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, lazy-loading, byte-code-enhancement

I'm currently reading Vlad Mihalcea's book [High-Performance Java Persistence](https://vladmihalcea.com/books/high-performance-java-persistence/).

In the Bytecode Enhancement section, it is said that `enableDirtyTracking` can optimize performance with large amounts of data through replacing reflections.  But I'm just wondering if there are any disadvantages?

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any or only very old information.

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <configuration>
            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
            <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
            <enableLazyInitialization>false</enableLazyInitialization>
            <enableAssociationManagement>false</enableAssociationManagement>
            <enableExtendedEnhancement>false</enableExtendedEnhancement>
         </configuration>
         <goals>
            <goal>enhance</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

And while doing further research in the Hibernate documentation I came across three more properties:

- `enableLazyInitialization`,
- `enableAssociationManagement`,
- `enableExtendedEnhancement`.

But I can't find much about it on the internet.

If I understood it correctly, `enableAssociationManagement` makes the independent handling of bidirectional relationships superfluous and replaces `enableLazyInitialization` like `enableDirtyTracking` Reflections?

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything about `enableExtendedEnhancement`. That's why I have the same question as above. Should I just use it? Or which disadvantages result from it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `enableAssociationManagement` only works from parent to child entities, not the other way around. So, it's not very useful. Better synchronize both ends of a bidirectional association using [add/remove methods](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/).

The [`enableLazyInitialization`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-lazy-load-entity-attributes-using-jpa-and-hibernate/) can be useful for lazy attributes, like fetching a parent-side `@OneToOne` association lazily, as by default, this one is fetched eagerly even when set to `FetchType.LAZY`.

The `enableDirtyTracking` setting is not needed if you make sure the Persistence Context never loads too many entities. You are better off reducing the Persistence Context size than using this setting.

The `enableExtendedEnhancement` setting allow a you to extends more than the entity classes, so bytecode enhancement can work even beyond calling getters and setters on entities. This setting is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @VladMihalcea, When I tried to use this plugin I found out that there are no abilities to select particular bytecode provider and entities to be enhanced. Could you please throw light to these questions?

Comment: In 2023, when using the [Spring Initiazr](https://start.spring.io), if your dependencies include _GraalVM_ and _Spring Data JPA_, the produced scaffold enables the properties `enableLazyInitialization`, `enableDirtyTracking` and `enableAssociationManagement`. I've had bugs with these settings when adding _add/remove_ methods :-(. I suppose I'll always starting my next projects by disabling those properties.